# Group BY Having COUNT, but Order on a column not contained in group

Tags: sql, t-sql

I have a table where I need to get the `ID`, for a group(based on `ID` and `Name`) with a `COUNT(*) = 3`, for the latest set of timestamps.

So for example below, I want to retrieve `ID 2`. As it has 3 rows, and the latest timestamps (even though `ID 3` has latest timestamps overall, it doesn't have a count of 3).

But I don't understand how to order by `Date`, as I cannot contain it in the `Group By` clause, as it is not the same:

```
SELECT TOP 1 ID
FROM TABLE
GROUP BY ID,Name
HAVING COUNT(ID) > 2
AND Name = 'ABC'
--ORDER BY Date DESC
```

**Sample Data**

```
ID  Name  Date
1   ABC   2015-05-27 08:00
1   ABC   2015-05-27 09:00
1   ABC   2015-05-27 10:00
2   ABC   2015-05-27 11:00
2   ABC   2015-05-27 12:00
2   ABC   2015-05-27 13:00
3   ABC   2015-05-27 14:00
3   ABC   2015-05-27 15:00
```

Comment: You can't. One ID can have several dates, conflicting order by wise with other id's.

Comment: Ok yes I realize I cannot given the way i have currently written the query, I worded question wrong. I am looking for a way to do this by ordering based on the date.

Comment: `ORDER BY Min(Date) DESC`, I think in your case it will work

Comment: Thank you Giorgi. ORDER BY MAX(Date) DESC works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In SQL server, you need aggregate the columns not on group by list:

```
SELECT TOP 1 ID
FROM TABLE
WHERE Name = 'ABC'
GROUP BY ID,Name
HAVING COUNT(ID) > 2
ORDER BY MAX(Date) DESC
```

The name filter should be put before the group by for better performance, if you really need it.

Comment: Thank you. I thought because Date times were all different i couldn't do this. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

You could do it in a nested query.

Subquery:

```
SELECT ID 
 from TABLE 
GROUP BY ID 
HAVING Count(ID) > 2
```

That gives you the IDs you want.  Put that in another query:

```
SELECT ID, Data 
  FROM Table 
Where ID in (Subquery)
Order by Date DESC;
```

Answer (score -1):

First get all desired IDs. That is all IDs having a count > 2. Get the maximum date for each such ID. Then rank these records with ROW_NUMBER, giving the latest ID #1. At last remove all IDs that are not ranked #1.

```
select name, id
from
(
  select 
    name, id, row_count() over (partition by name order by max_date desc) as rn
  from
  (
    select name, id, max(date) as max_date
    from mytable
    --where name = 'ABC'
    group by name, id
    having count(*) > 2
  ) wanted_ids
) ranked_ids
where rn = 1;
```